# What's the difference between a gerund acting as a noun, and an infinitive acting as a noun, as well?

Tags: nouns, gerunds, infinitives

I asked this question at the end of class, and the teacher told me:

"They do not have the same meaning. A gerund represents any instance of an action, while an infinitive represents the concept of an action"

But, I don't undertand what he meant. I'd be thankful, if you could answer my question. Thanks.

Comment: I'd be surprised if any native speaker saw any meaningful difference between *I hate giving him a hard time* and *I hate to give him a hard time.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The difference in meaning between to infinitive and gerund in these sentences](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/593716/the-difference-in-meaning-between-to-infinitive-and-gerund-in-these-sentences) Where both catenation patterns are licensed by say a given verb, there may or may not be a difference in meaning. tchrist's example: negligible if any difference. In 'he stopped to watch' and 'he stopped watching', a vast difference.

Comment: Your teacher said a gerund is more specific than an infinitive. **To** be or not to be = in general, do I even want to live? Summertime, and the **living** is easy = It is hot and I am happy now.

Comment: See also [When should a verb be followed by a gerund instead of an infinitive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329/when-should-a-verb-be-followed-by-a-gerund-instead-of-an-infinitive). // In usages like 'To err is human ...', the to-infinitive is more punchy than the ing-form.

Comment: *I hate to give him a hard time*. Means: I don't want to do it in a particular situation. Whereas: *I hate giving him a hard time*. implies you do and you hate it. Native speaker. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/386451/which-expression-is-correct-ive-already-started-working-on-it-or-ive-alrea/386459#386459

Comment: One obvious difference is that infinitivals don't act as nouns. The traditional gerund verb, however, does have a noun form, best called a gerundial noun (or just noun), e.g. "He was expelled for **killing** the birds" (verb) ~ "I witnessed the **killing** of the birds" (gerundial noun). Note that the classification of non-finite subordinate clauses is based on the classification of the head verb form rather than spurious analogies with the parts of speech.